# P/Invoke sometimes cause Win32 1008 Error with StringBuilder parameters

Tags: c#, interop, pinvoke

I have a DLL from which I need to P/Invoke the following C method:

```
int DAStart(
    HANDLE hOpen,
    char* IPAddress,
    int IPPort,
    int threadPriority,
    char* name,
    char* password,
    char* userName)
```

Using the P/Invoke Assistant and my own research, I've come up with the following C# signature:

```
[DllImportAttribute("<libName>", EntryPoint="DAStart")]  
static extern  int DAStart(  
    IntPtr hOpen,  
    [MarshalAs(Unmanaged.LPStr)] StringBuilder IPAddress,
    int IPPort,
    int threadPriority, 
    [MarshalAs(Unmanaged.LPStr)] StringBuilder name, 
    [MarshalAs(Unmanaged.LPStr)] StringBuilder password,   
    [MarshalAs(Unmanaged.LPStr)] StringBuilder userName);
```

Now, I'm doing the call in the following way:

```
int port = 3000;
int threadPriority = 20;

DAStart(
    this.nativeDllHandle, // an IntPtr class field  
    new StringBuilder("10.0.10.1"),
    int port,
    int threadPriority,
    new StringBuilder("admin"),
    new StringBuilder("admin"),
    new StringBuilder("admin"));
```

Now, sometimes this works just fine, but something I get a Win32 Error `1008 - An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist` on following calls to this library.

Could it be that my StringBuilder objects get garbage collected so that the reference no longer exist if the native code tries to use it? Should I keep a reference for each one of them?

Would an IntPtr be better solution for passing my strings in that case?

** **UPDATE** **

This is all the API documentation I have for DAStart:

**Inputs**
HANDLE hInfo The handle returned by the DAOpen
char *IPAdress_in IP Address of the TMEE Server
int IPPort Console Port of the TMEE Server (default is port 3000)
int threadPriority The thread priority for the send file thread.
char *name Not used in Hardware DLL
char *password Not used in Hardware DLL
char *username Not used in Hardware DLL

**Returns**
ERROR_SUCCESS 0
ERROR_BAD_HANDLE -1
ERROR_BIND_FAILED -10

**Comments**
The DAStart API connects the client dll to the active TMEE Server service. The client thread is started with a priority set to the threadPriority parameter. The IP address parameter must be set to the address of the TMEE Server. The port parameter must be set to the port the TMEE Server listens on for Console connections (the default port the Consoles use is 3010). The Console thread is started with a priority set to the threadPriority parameter.

Comment: Please don't type code in. Use the clipboard. That way we can try to debug the real code.

Comment: Do you have any documentation for DAStart? What does it say?

Comment: @DavidHefferman The machine I'm coding on is not connected to the internet or local network, nor does it have USB. Otherwise, I would have copy/pasted it.

Comment: @DavidHefferman I included the DAStart API documentation.

Comment: Looks like you can pass `NULL` for the final 3 parameters. I have to say, I can't understand why this function would modify the string parameters. I also can't really believe it doesn't take a copy of the input data. That's shockingly bad form. Are you sure that calling convention is `stdcall`?

Comment: @DavidHefferman I was also surprised to see it modify the strings I passed in parameters. I'm guessing it only takes the pointer without making copies, which is, as you say bad form. And yes, I'm using stdcalls.

Comment: if it takes pointers without making copies then string builder won't help. In that case you will need to allocate the memory with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` and pass in the string parameters as `IntPtr`. See my comment to your accepted answer.

Comment: @DavidHefferman I see exactly what you mean... I guess keeping a field is correcting the immediate problem of getting GC'ed right away, but it's not foolproof if the GC rearranges memory... I really need to use `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Right. Using static field masks it for now. Then the bug will reappear two years down the line and manifest only on your most important client's machine at a critical point and you'll have forgotten all about this. Or perhaps I'm just being a pessimist! If you feel the accepted answer is wrong then you can unaccept. Otherwise you will give a false impression to future visitors.

Comment: I do something in one of my dlls with static properties and a delegate and it has  been running without a problem for years. Static attributes get initialized at startup, thus the likelihood of moving is very, very small. IntPrt and AllocHGlobal is cleaner and safer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the comments you indicate that the DLL takes a copy of the `char*` pointers (and not the contents of the strings) and then modifies the contents of the strings **after** `DAStart` returns.

In the face of this very unconventional interface design your only option is to take charge of the marshaling of the string parameters. You cannot use `StringBuilder` since the `char*` passed to the native code is valid only during the pinvoke call. It cannot be relied upon to be valid after the pinvoke call returns.

So your only solution is to pass the string parameters as `IntPtr`. Allocate the memory with `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi`. Pass the resulting `IntPtr` to `DAStart`. When you are sure the DLL is done with the pointer, deallocate with `Marshal.FreeHGlobal`.

Answer (score -3):

References outside the managed environment are unknown to the Garbage collector. 
Thus you need to keep an additional reference somewhere as long as you need to the object - easiest is via a static property in the calling class. 
An IntPtr does not make a difference - it will get collected as well.

Comment: I don't really understand this. I can't see that it helps.

Comment: The thing is that the questions says "on following calls" to the library. These calls might happen later and then the StringBuilder might be collected because there was no known reference for the GC.

Comment: @weismat I do think you are exactly right... Keeping a reference of the stringbuilders seems to prevent the error!

Comment: I remember spending a whole day to find the solution on a similar problem with a function pointer/delegate between managed code and a C dll.

Comment: -1 This cannot be the solution. One of the first rules of DLL interface design is that you take copies of the `char*` data that is input. If the DLL really is failing to do that and is instead taking a reference then simply making the `StringBuilder` static does not help. The pointer passed to the DLL when marshalling with `StringBuilder` is only valid for the pinvoke call. Just imagine what happens when the GC moves the `StringBuilder` object.